# Alternative to audio jack

Tags: laptop, audio

Audio jack in my laptop is not working.

What would be the best alternative for that, like usb to audio converter or usb to hdmi converter?

Comment: usb to audio. I had one come with a pair of headphones once, I've used it many times for many reasons.

Comment: I kindly request to mention the reason for downvoting

Comment: Its totally unfair to downvote without any proper reasoning / editing. A proper rules should be mentioned in prior or the downvoting should not be allowed. I think people are misusing the points for their personal grudge.Overall monitoring is required.

Comment: Note that if the failure is due to a mechanical failure in the jack, a local laptop repair outfit can likely fix that for a relatively small sum.  But also consider that the jack may be disabled in software or the driver may have been clobbered and need reloading.

Comment: We can only give some option, you have to choose, but you gave us options and asked us to choose. (I did not down-vote, but maybe that is the reason.)

Comment: Well, this isn't a very good question - its a purchase recommendation however you look at it, and you're asking between two devices with no details at all about your usecase even if it was. I can *entirely* understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A USB sound card will resolve this**. You can get USB headphones but these aren't very useful if you want to plug in speakers or a microphone...

Comment: **They sell headphones with Microphones on them.**

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that... but, to be most versatile, a sound card will allow the user to plug in whatever speakers or microphone they already have... or even use the built-in microphone that most laptops have... My answer is practically identical to YetiFiasco's... was the downvote really justifiable?

Comment: It's not really a "card" tho.  Just a simple adapter: http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/detail-page/B005QUQP6W_usb_adapter.jpg

Comment: The device you have there is a USB sound card. You need to convert the audio (digital) to serial data (for USB) -> The USB sound-card needs to then be able to decode that data back into analog audio (for headphones/speakers)(using DACs) so, no, it isn't simply an "adapter". It is a complete sound device - it just uses USB to interface with your computer - much like adding a PCI audio card - PCI is the interface.

Comment: @BigChris You sound like your question whether the adapter works? indeed it does using a standard windows driver. I've used it on computer without audio jacks, with laptop that had the jack in an inconvenient place, and during a presentation to pipe the computer audio to a public address system. It's plug-n-play and always works without downloading or installing.  They are inexpensive and easy to find from multiple makers.

Comment: Sorry, Tyson, I'm not questioning whether it works, I'm just stating that it is still a "sound card" - Windows (and Mac) may have drivers for it "built-in", but if it requires drivers it is still not simply an "adapter" (say, DVI-to-VGA).

Answer (score 1):

Your easiest and best alternative would be to buy a USB version of the device that you are using. Failing that, there are multiple **USB soundcards** on the market that have both a **line in** (mic) and **line out** (speakers) audio jack, these are pretty inexpensive and many of them are just plug and play, requiring no additional drivers.